# SSH into multiple servers executing multiple commands

Tags: ssh, scripting

I have several hosts that need to have a one-off RPM installed as well as packages belonging to the CentOS-Debuginfo.repo.  These machines currently have the repo disabled and gpgcheck enabled.  After everything has been installed, I need rpm --nodeps -e some packages, all the while echo'ing out the hostname of each machine that this has all been done to.

So far, I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# SSH to hosts, then grab the GTS RPM and install it.  Yum install required debugging packages, then rpm to erase unnneeded ones.

cmds="echo $HOSTNAME; cd /tmp && wget http://download.sipxcom.org/pub/epel.bak/6/x86_64/gts-0.7.6-19.20111025.el6.x86_64.rpm /tmp; rpm -i /tmp/gts-0.7.6-19.20111025.el6.x86_64.rpm; yum --enablerepo debug --nogpg install -y db4-debuginfo.x86_64 expat-debuginfo.x86_64 glibc-debuginfo.x86_64 kernel-devel.x86_64 nss-softokn-debuginfo.x86_64 openssl-debuginfo.x86_64 python-debuginfo.x86_64 readline-debuginfo.x86_64 zlib-debuginfo.x86_64; for i in $(cat /tmp/testing/rpms_to_erase.txt); do rpm -e $i; done"
hostlist=/tmp/testing/hostlist.txt

for i in $HOSTLIST
  do
    ssh -qn $i "bash $CMDS" && "rpm -e gdm-plugin-fingerprint.x86_64 gdm-user-switch-applet.x86_64 gnome-applets.x86_64"
  done
```

As you can see, this is quite ugly.  Wondering if anyone may have a more elegant solution.

Comment: Ansible, perhaps, or one the many existing SSH multiplexers would be better options.

Comment: I completely agree.  Unfortunately, we're not allowed to install any additional packages/management tools without going through a rigorous process.

Comment: `clusterssh` or `tmux` on your client device (no changes required on the servers).

Answer (score 2):

Clusterssh (command cssh) lets you ssh to multiple hosts at once

```
cssh server1 server2 server3
```

and then whatever you type, it appears in all terminals once active.